# ASP.NET MVC Authentification Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, authentication

I need to deny all access to any controller if they do not login.
I do not want to do this for each entry:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult AnyMethod() {
...
}
```

I try something like that but this was denied access to everything (css, js, ...).

```
<authorization>
     <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

In the Web.config I have only this code:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="Account/Login"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the Authorize attribute on the controller instead -- it can be applied to both methods and classes.  This will save you a lot of work and still give your users access to your static content (that isn't protected via the web.config).

```
 [Authorize]
 public class AdminController : Controller
 {
     ...
     public ActionResult SetPassword( UserPasswordModel model )
     {
         ...
     }
     ...
 }
```